# How to refer a iframe from html in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've just started learning html and CSS and now I want to add a bit JavaScript which I don't know anything of!

I want to create a random button that shows a random embed video (for instance from 1-5 videos) in a iframe. I searched google and found a JavaScript/(jQuery?):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var array=["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"];
$('#button').bind('click', function() {

    var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    $("h1").html(random);
});
});
</script>
```

With the html:

```
<h1>Will be replaced</h1>
<button id="button">Random</button>
```

So for example in my html I got:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/npvNPORFXpc"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want this embedded video to show on the page and when u hit the random button it should change to 1-5 video's. How do i set this as a item in the JavaScript, so I have a video on each item?

Problem 2:

Sometimes the same number is generated which will lead to the same item.

I hope someone can teach me something about this!

Comment: If you hit the second time on the random button, should the iframe be replaced by another or just another iframe should be added to the page?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, i would like the iframe being replaced in the same position as it is. Or should the video in the iframe be replaced if that is even possible? by using a source option in js?

Comment: Well, you cold set a new src to the iframe...I'll make a small script in a few minutes to demonstrate ...

Comment: Thanks! ill be waiting to see it

Comment: if you give the iframe an ID you can easily select it the same fashion you're selecting the button: `<iframe id="video">` can be selected with `$("#video")` and then you can set the src attribute using `$("#video").attr("src", newUrlHere)` https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

It may not be much , but is a starting point : 
[Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/BH6UT/2/)

Just got the first 5 video id's I could found :))

Here is the Js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array=["FOIjvHjK0Rw", "CcsUYu0PVxY", "dE_XVl7fwBQ", "iIwxR6kjTfA", "USe6s2kfuWk"];
    $('#button').bind('click', function() {
        var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        $("h1").html(random);
        var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+random;
        $('#frame').attr('src', url);
        $('#frame').css('visibility','visible');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't use jQuery often :))...I prefer plain js

Comment: The essential parts here are plain JS, with jquery it's easier to select using css syntax and bind event handlers (cross browser). Here is a plain JS version using the same logic: http://jsfiddle.net/BH6UT/3/

Comment: Thanks that helps alot! now i dont need the header anymore to see the random button working. Now the only problem is that it generates the same video sometimes, how can i exclude the active video of generating again?

Comment: The Alot appreciates all the help it can get! :) http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.no/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: Do you really want to use jQuery?..I think it would be easier in plain javascript...

Comment: @user3375841 You could keep track of the previous video ID in a variable, and keep getting a random one until it doesnt match: http://jsfiddle.net/BH6UT/4/

Comment: I will use plain javascript on your advice, seems alot easier to understand as i just started with js :). it works! learned something new thanks guys!